# Excel: Form Control Combo Box to change Pivot Table Filters: Getting Errors

Tags: combobox, pivot

I'm creating a dashboard and have some pivot charts and form control combo boxes on one sheet, then the pivot tables on another sheet.  I want what you select in the combo box drop down to change the filter on the pivot table, so that it will change the chart on the dashboard sheet.  I found some code online to do this and it worked great.  I select "West" from the combo box and it changes the pivot table to display the west region which in turn chnages the pivot chart on my dashboard.

Problem is, I'm now getting error messages for no reason.  I didn't change anything in the sheet at all but am all of the sudden getting VB error messages saying "Code execution has been interupted".  If i hit continue it executes perfectly.  If i hit debug, sometimes simply "End sub" is highlighted, sometimes, other stuff is.  Its random.  Im perplexed.  I can't deply this dashbaord to end users w/ this error message popping up constantly.  Can someone take a look at this and let me know what's going on? I'm using excel 2007.  If you need the sourcefile I'll email it to you.  Thanks for the help!

```
Sub weekly_select_region()
'
' weekly_select_region Macro
' selects the region from the weekly pivot table
'

'
    Sheets("Weekly Pivots").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Weekly Quote Production Pivot").PivotFields("Region").CurrentPage _
        = Range("N2").Text
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Weekly Re-Quote Production Pivot").PivotFields("Region").CurrentPage _
        = Range("N2").Text
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End Sub

Sub weekly_select_segment()
'
' weekly_select_segment Macro
' selects the segment from the weekly pivot table
'

'
    Sheets("Weekly Pivots").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Weekly Quote Production Pivot").PivotFields("Segment"). _
        CurrentPage = Range("O2").Text
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Weekly Re-Quote Production Pivot").PivotFields("Segment"). _
        CurrentPage = Range("O2").Text
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably just a leftover breakpoint.
In Code editor, from the menu, choose Debug -> Clear all breakpoints.

Also you could add this line at the start of the subroutine,
On Error Resume Next